# Recyclerview addOnScrollListener method not working in nested Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

- I am trying to paginate a **recyclerview** inside another **recyclerview**.Both have vertical  `LinearLayoutManager` o Consider them as `childRv` and `parentRV`.
- The issue here is that whenever I try to paginate `childRV` the `addOnScrollListener` method doesn't work. I didn't find any solution to it.
- I am using `childRV` inside this : [SectionedRecyclerview](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter)

Comment: having a vertical RV inside a another Vertical RV will cause these types of Problem . That's why its not recommended and its also break the recycling part . There are other ways to create Sectioned RV look into them. Or you might wanna re-thing your UI if your inner one have paging. maybe have Inner RV as Horizontal .

Comment: Both parentRV and childRV have vertical linear layout.